# How should i check hashed passwords

Tags: php, hash, crypt

I use  crypt ( password , $2y$10$predefinedsalt) to generate hashes.. Is it okay to just check them with other hashes using a normal if?

```
$password = crypt ( password , $2y$10$predefinedsalt);
$password2 -> from database)
if(password == password2)
{
     then do something
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using password_hash() and password_verify()? Then you'd already have a known and correct way to deal with password hashing

Comment: the database with passwords already exists and i cannot change them. So i have to use the predefined salt, and thats not possible with password_hash()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that's pretty much how password verification works.

You store the original password hashed and on login you hash the entered password with the same options/hash and compare it to the one you've stored earlier

PHP recommends using `hash_equals()` to mitigate timing attacks. Like this:

```php
return hash_equals($hash, crypt($password, $salt));
```